# Do repeated call of set_target_properties overwrite the previous value of the target property in CMake?

Tags: cmake

I have a CMake file where I have the following command:

```
set_target_properties(SM_Application PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME "Initial_Name.lib" PREFIX "" SUFFIX "")
...
set_target_properties(SM_Application PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME "New_Name.lib" PREFIX "" SUFFIX "")
```

Will the second call of `set_target_properties` change the property `OUTPUT_NAME`?

I wanted to try debugging this myself by logging this property with the message command like so:

```
message("Initialize output names for libs: ${SM_Application } ")
```

But that didn't work. I don't know how to access the target property `OUTPUT_NAME`.

Answer (score 1):

[`set_target_properties`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set_target_properties.html)

> You can use any prop value pair you want and extract it later with the `get_property()` or `get_target_property()` command.

This answers *How can i log this property with the message command?*

With accessing a set value to the property `OUTPUT_NAME`, you can ensure the second `set_target_properties` rewrites the first one.

Answer (score 0):

To print a target property with `message`, you need to read it out into a CMake variable, and then reference the variable in the content argument of `message`.

This config creates an executable target, sets the target property, reads it out into a variable, prints the value with message, and then repeats with a different value.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.25)
project(hello_world)

add_executable(SM_Application main.cpp)
set_target_properties(SM_Application PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME "Initial_Name.lib" PREFIX "" SUFFIX "")
get_target_property(SM_Application_OUTPUT_NAME SM_Application OUTPUT_NAME)
message("SM_Application_OUTPUT_NAME: ${SM_Application_OUTPUT_NAME}")
set_target_properties(SM_Application PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME "New_Name.lib" PREFIX "" SUFFIX "")
get_target_property(SM_Application_OUTPUT_NAME SM_Application OUTPUT_NAME)
message("SM_Application_OUTPUT_NAME: ${SM_Application_OUTPUT_NAME}")
```

The output:

```
...
SM_Application_OUTPUT_NAME: Initial_Name.lib
SM_Application_OUTPUT_NAME: New_Name.lib
...
```

So yes, repeated calls of `set_target_properties` overwrite previous values. If you want to append instead of overwriting, use the more general [`set_property(TARGET)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set_property.html), which has a `APPEND` option (but doesn't allow setting multiple properties in the same call).